# Power Down a Locked Device

Tags: samsung, password, pattern-lock

So I brought a Samsung S7 while on a trip, quickly ran through the setup, adding a fingerprint and a pattern password. I didn't pay much attention to the pattern password, as I had the fingerprint.

What I didn't realise is that you need the pattern password every time you power on, and now I've forgotten it.

What I'm now trying to do is turn the phone off, so I can turn it back on using `Power + Volume + Home` combination and reset the phone. But it seems to be asking for my pattern before it can turn off.

So how can I turn the phone off?

Comment: Try power button + volume down at the same time for about 10 secs or more

Comment: `adb shell reboot -p` should power off

Comment: Holding the power button for a very long time should force a power down

Comment: I wasn't able to turn it off, but what I was able to do was restart it, and then hold the button combination mentioned in the question.